# Hibernate QueryException: 'Not all named parameters have been set' - with native query containing ::int

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, postgresql-8.4

in our current project we need a query of the long-matching-prefix type but the column was oddly enough defined as *bigint*. We came up with the solution in the snippet below, where we want to find the longest number in column *dc* that matches the parameter *?2* and *?3*, and *?1* date is between the 2 date columns.

Here are the relevant dependencies:

- Postresql 8.4
- Hibernate 3.6.10
- Hibernate JPA 1.0.1
- Spring 3.2.1

Here is the source:

```
...
String query_string = "SELECT * FROM numberlist WHERE " +
            "?1 BETWEEN init_date AND COALESCE(end_date,'2999-12-31') " +
            "AND dc IN " +
            "(select ?2/(10^i)::int8 from generate_series(0,floor(log(?3))::int) i) " +
            "ORDER BY dc DESC LIMIT 1";

Query query = emf.createEntityManager().createNativeQuery(query_string, MyNumber.class);
    query.setParameter(1, valid_date);
    query.setParameter(2, num);
    query.setParameter(3, num);

MyNumber result = (MyNumber)query.getSingleResult();
...
```

We are getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [:int8, :int]
```

We think the problem is Hibernate taking *:int* and *:int8* as parameters but cannot find the solution.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in my comment above, I ended up using:

```
public class LegacyDao extends JdbcDaoSupport
```

In this way, I was able to reuse the DataSource Hibernate was using.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite `(select ?2/(10^i)::int8` as `CAST((select ?2/(10^i) AS INT8)`.
In general, any type cast can be written as both `<data>::<type>` and `CAST(<data> AS <type>)`.
This forms are identical and will give identical results.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use:

```
query.setParameter(":int8", valid_date);
```

instead of:

```
query.setParameter(1, valid_date);
```

Comment: Hi, I ended up with _public class LegacyDao extends JdbcDaoSupport_ so I reuse the DataSource Hibernate is using and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting double `\` before `:`

```
...
String query_string = "SELECT * FROM numberlist WHERE " +
            "?1 BETWEEN init_date AND COALESCE(end_date,'2999-12-31') " +
            "AND dc IN " +
            "(select ?2/(10^i)\\:\\:int8 from generate_series(0,floor(log(?3))\\:\\:int) i) " +
            "ORDER BY dc DESC LIMIT 1";

Query query = emf.createEntityManager().createNativeQuery(query_string, MyNumber.class);
    query.setParameter(1, valid_date);
    query.setParameter(2, num);
    query.setParameter(3, num);

MyNumber result = (MyNumber)query.getSingleResult();
...
```